# Quadtree and division into equal subquadrants

Tags: c, quadtree

If I want to traverse a quadtree, do the dimensions have to be only 2^n ?
If not, what if it cannot be divided into equal subquadrants? for example, 5x6 table with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this problem.

First of all, your subdivisions are entirely arbitrary. You can set up the first subdivision to interpret your table 5x6 table dimensions as [1 + 4] x [2 + 4]. Then your four quadrants would be 1x2, 1x4, 4x2 and 4x4. At this point you can recurse as dimensions are 2^n.

To make this transparent to your code, you can define functions to map between quad tree coordinates and table indices.

Comment: but why does the theory explain that it divides data in 4 EQUAL subquadrants? sorry if I'm bugging you but I need to understand this. :)

Comment: MX and PR Quadtrees have an equal division of space. I'd suggest also looking at Point Quadtrees, where the boundaries of the quadrants are dictated entirely on the points in the trees (quadrants are of unequal size).